# Java - convert date formatted String from SQL db to date object for comparison

Tags: java, sql, date, format, simpledateformat

I have a string stored in a database (example: `Sat Jul 09 14:20:31 EDT 2011`)

This is stored as string (I am aware of SQLs date capabilities, but I'm not exploring that at this point).

I want to pull this strong and compare it with the current time using the `Date.compare` function

`Date currentDate = new Date();  // the new current time value
mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(TIMECOLUMN)`  //the old stored time value, pulled from the SQL database

From the database I have a string value already formatted as a proper date. But I don't have an obvious function to compare this to my current date as a date object.

I need to know if one is greater than, less than, or equal to, the other. The Date `compare` function will allow this, but the object needs to be a date object.

I have tried `SimpleDateFormat` seeded with the string's date format, but I get a parse exception "unparsable date", perhaps because it is already formatted?

`Date currentDate = new Date();

SimpleDateFormat dateTest = new SimpleDateFormat("E M d HH:mm:ss z y");
if(currentDate.compareTo(dateTest.parse((mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(TIMECOLUMN))))) > 0)`

returns `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: Sat Jul 09 14:20:31 EDT 2011`

I suspect my SimpleDateFormat seed is incorrect. Insight Appreciated

Comment: The exception means just that: the string you are trying to parse does not match the patter that you have set. Revisit SimpleDateFormat documentation, make a few tries and you will which is the problem.

Comment: [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you just need to change the "M" to "MMM" in your format string:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM d HH:mm:ss z y");
```

"M" is a potentially-single-digit value, e.g. 1, 10 etc. "MMM" is a short month name (e.g. "Jul", "Sep").

However, you should probably *also* specify the locale of the date format. I'd also *strongly* encourage you to break your currently huge statement into several bits to make it easier to understand *and* debug:

```
int timeColumn = mCursor.getColumnIndex(TIMECOLUMN);
String dbDateText = mCursor.getString(timeColumn);
Date dbDate = format.parse(dbDateText);

if (currentDate.compareTo(dbDate) > 0) {
}
```

I'd also encourage you to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) for date/time-related work, and to avoid storing date/time data as text in the database :)

Comment: I agree, see http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html: excerpt: **Pattern letters are usually repeated, as their number determines the exact presentation:** Maybe it's something like `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`.

Comment: +1 for the Joda Time suggestion. This really needs more mindshare.  Of course, Joda uses the same format strings, so the question is applicable in either case. :)

Comment: @Ray: I mention Joda Time in virtually every date/time answer I give on Java :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes the date format is incorrect.  Here is a demo:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
        System.out.println(new Date());
        String string = "Sat Jul 09 14:20:31 EDT 2011";
        System.out.println(df.parse(string));
    } 
}
```