# Getting the Date format in Java

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am have this `String` from a `Date` object: `Mon Mar 25 00:00:00 IST 2013`

What is the `String` representation of the date format?

Comment: refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html and try something yourself before post a question

Comment: Please avoid asking questions that do not show any intent of research on your behalf. [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: **"EEE, MMM d, ''yy"** from [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html]

Comment: You will find your answer in this subject [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636375/java-convert-date-formatted-string-from-sql-db-to-date-object-for-comparison][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636375/java-convert-date-formatted-string-from-sql-db-to-date-object-for-comparison

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code below should work fine.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String target = "Mon Mar 25 00:00:00 IST 2013";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date result =  df.parse(target);  
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Read the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for the valid patterns.

Answer (score 2):

```
String yourDate= "Mon Mar 25 00:00:00 IST 2013" ;
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
Date jDate = new Date(df.parse(yourDate).getTime());
System.out.println(jDate);
```