# Convert java.util.date default format to Timestamp in Java

Tags: java, date, time, timestamp, java.util.date

The default format of java.util.date is something like this "Mon May 27 11:46:15 IST 2013". How can I convert this into timestamp and calculate in seconds the difference between the same and current time?

```
java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
Timestamp ts_now = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
```

The above code gives me the current timestamp. However, I got no clue how to find the timestamp of the above string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: I am afraid not, I was working on the timestamp format.

Comment: Duplicate: [Java: Convert String to TimeStamp](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18915075/642706)

Comment: SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy");

This was what I needed..(look at the format type)


However, the link you provided uses 

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");

Wouldn't have worked for my case.

Comment: And duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4496359/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15546494/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4216745/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20165071/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16336643/642706) and many more.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `Calendar` class to convert `Date`

```
public long getDifference()
{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy");
    Date d = sdf.parse("Mon May 27 11:46:15 IST 2013");

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(d);
    long time = c.getTimeInMillis();
    long curr = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long diff = curr - time;    //Time difference in milliseconds
    return diff/1000;
}
```

Comment: While am trying to convert "Mon May 27 11:46:15 IST 2013" string to date. It gives me an unparsable string exception. Any idea how can I go about?

Comment: thanks a lot @Rahul . I actually combined your answer with Salem's answer above to get this right. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 8):

Best one

```
String str_date=month+"-"+day+"-"+yr;
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date); 
long output=date.getTime()/1000L;
String str=Long.toString(output);
long timestamp = Long.parseLong(str) * 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
  long startTime = date.getTime() * 1000000;;
  long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
```

To get time in nano.

[Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29)

Comment: How did it convert the string I passed?

Comment: I want to convert "Mon May 27 11:46:15 IST 2013" this string into timestamp. And find the difference between it and the current time..that too in seconds.

Comment: Am s database freak...Java is confusing me.

Comment: Thanks @Nidhin, I found the work around with Salem and Rahul's answer below. Appreciate your quick help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateFormat`(java.text.*) to parse the date:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date d = df.parse("Mon May 27 11:46:15 IST 2013")
```

You will have to change the locale to match your own (with this you will get 10:46:15). Then you can use the same code you have to convert it to a timestamp.

Comment: Thank you! I used your answer along with @Rahul 's to get this right.

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

I am providing the modern answer. The `Timestamp` class was always poorly designed, a real hack on top of the already poorly designed `Date` class. Both those classes are now long outdated. Don’t use them.

When the question was asked, you would need a `Timestamp` for sending a point in time to the SQL database. Since JDBC 4.2 that is no longer the case. Assuming your database needs a `timestamp with time zone` (recommended for true timestamps), pass it an `OffsetDateTime`.

Before we can do that we need to overcome a real trouble with your sample string, `Mon May 27 11:46:15 IST 2013`: the time zone abbreviation. `IST` may mean Irish Summer Time, Israel Standard Time or India Standard Time (I have even read that Java may parse it into Atlantic/Reykjavik time zone — Icelandic Standard Time?) To control the interpretation we pass our preferred time zone to the formatter that we are using for parsing.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ")
            .appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT, Set.of(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")))
            .appendPattern(" yyyy")
            .toFormatter(Locale.ROOT);
    String dateString = "Mon May 27 11:46:15 IST 2013";
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = formatter.parse(dateString, Instant::from)
            .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

This snippet prints:

> 2013-05-27T06:16:15Z

This is the UTC equivalent of your string (assuming IST was for India Standard Time). Pass the `OffsetDateTime` to your database using one of the `PreparedStatement.setObject` methods (not `setTimestamp`).

> How can I convert this into timestamp and calculate in seconds the
>   difference between the same and current time?

Calculating the difference in seconds goes very naturally with java.time:

```
    long differenceInSeconds = ChronoUnit.SECONDS
            .between(dateTime, OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC));
    System.out.println(differenceInSeconds);
```

When running just now I got:

> 202213260

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.