# Matching java time stamp to sql timestamp?

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to pass a date field into a table. The column is of sql timestamp and I keep getting the runtime exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff] at 
java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(Timestamp.java:235)
at kafkaTest.TruckScheme.deserialize(TruckScheme.java:51) 
at backtype.storm.spout.SchemeAsMultiScheme.deserialize(SchemeAsMultiScheme.java:33) 
at storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.generateTuples(KafkaUtils.java:189) 
at storm.kafka.PartitionManager.next(PartitionManager.java:121) at storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.nextTuple(KafkaSpout.java:124) 
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4949$fn__4964$fn__4993.invoke(executor.clj:585) 
at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__452.invoke(util.clj:465) 
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I tried to format it using `SimpleFateFormat` but I am still getting the same error. 
Is there any way to get the java date format to comply with the exact format that of the sql timestamp type?

Thanks.
Piyush

Comment: Could you share your code snippet?

Comment: Add source code so we can help.

Comment: Does SimpleDateFormat create a datetime object or a string?  If it's the latter, don't do it that way.  Send a datetime object as a query parameter.

Comment: maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915075/java-convert-string-to-timestamp

Comment: Sorry for late , I got is working using 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS");. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

With using milisecond level SimpleDateFormatter, you can match them. Please try like this;

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
    String DateToStoreInDataBase= sdf.format(new Date()); // java.util.Date
    System.out.println(DateToStoreInDataBase);

    Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(DateToStoreInDataBase); // java.sql.Timestamp
    System.out.println(ts);
  }
```

And the result is;

```
2015-05-12 09:02:02.645
2015-05-12 09:02:02.645
```

Answer (score 1):

my problem was because of format , thank you

```
SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
```