# Exception while formatting the parameter" "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'T'

Tags: java, timestamp, simpledateformat

```
String dateFormat="Timestamp";
String timeVal ="2015-11-13 05:30:00.0";

return new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat).format(new Date((((Timestamp) timeVal).getTime())));
```

Comment: What kind of date format do you think that is?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
String dateFormat="Timestamp";
```

use

```
String dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
```

If your date is like

```
String timeVal ="2015-11-13 05:30:00";
```

Here you must use date and time format of your date and time.

[SimpleDateFormat doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: hai just i want to convert dateFormat to timestamp

Comment: @bakesh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915075/java-convert-string-to-timestamp