# How to compare two utc timestamps in Java?

Tags: java, timestamp, utc

I am using the below method to generate a UTC timestamp and would like to compare it with another. I am using Apache Commons Lang library for this.

How can I compare the two timestamps and determine which one is bigger?

```
String msgPushedTimestamp = 2016-05-11T19:50:17.141Z
String logFileTimestamp = 2016-05-11T14:52:02.970Z
```

This is how I am generating the timestamp using Apache Commons Lang library.

```
String msgPushedTimestamp = FastDateFormat.getInstance("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")).format(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915075/java-convert-string-to-timestamp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can compare them as strings because your date format ([ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)) is lexicographically comparable.

```
int compare = msgPushedTimestamp.compareTo(logFileTimestamp);
if (compare < 0) {
    // msgPushedTimestamp is earlier
} else if (compare > 0) {
    // logFileTimestamp is earlier
} else {
    // they are equal
}
```

Comment: Perfect  ! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

Have the class implement Comparable interface, you can use core Java's compareTo method. Works on timestamp in String type, as this is your case.

Comment: I am actually using a Junit test. Can Junit actually implement  Comparable interface ?

Comment: Not tried on this one. But I used interfaces and JUnit before and they worked fine.