# Unable to Parse String Date to Timestamp in java

Tags: java, date, java.util.date

My Date format Example = "jan 14, 2015" Now I convert this string date to Timestamp But this Code Throws ParseException.

```
format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);

     try {

          format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Bangladesh"));
          Date date = format.parse(str_date);
          Timestamp timeStampDate = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());

          return timeStampDate;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
          e.getCause().printStackTrace();
          return null;
        }
```

So How can I Solve this Exception??? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Well yes, look at the string you've got vs the format you're specifying... where are the hour/minute/second values?

Comment: Can you show us the whole code? Is there a difference between `format` and `formatter` or where is the last one defined? What is `str_date`? What's the text of the printed `ParseException`?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30341685/1966655

Answer (score 4):

change your pattern to: `format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);` because you do not have a time part

Comment: Thanks It Works @ Jens